# Seeking C unit test system

Tags: c, unit-testing

It has been a few years since I coded any C (or C++) and now I have to code an application to run on a micro-controller. Development will be on a Windows 7, 64-bit PC, which is where the unit tests will run.

Last time out I was using CppUnit, but am not sure of what might have changegd in the past few years and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C) offers so many choices that I might spend weeks trying them all out.

What meets this wish-list?

- can handle plain C (gcc under Cygwin)
- quick learning curve
- good documentation, including examples, and support (forums)
- can generate stubs (mocks?) from header files
- I am using NetBeans as IDE if that makes any difference
- Integrates with Hudson is a bonus
- a GUI might be nice, all other things being equal
- I am slowly coming round to TDD, if that makes any difference

Plus anything else you can think of. Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of micro-controller (a 16 bits or a 32 bits processor, e.g. some ARM)?? DO you code a free-standing system, or is there some operating system on it (e.g. embedded Linux)?

Comment: +1 but I am have to say that the actual board has still to be decided. That does not however mean that I don't yet have a design or even some code. I have already started coding the parts which can be and would like to unit test the code on a Windows PC asap. I doubt that it will be a powerful processor. It must support an 8 bit bus and max 32 rather simple peripherals

Comment: Check unit test framework meets most of your requirements. http://check.sourceforge.net/

Comment: a) How will you simulate peripherals?  How will you test the implementation of their actual drivers? b) Best practices with any testing methodology includes test coverage.  Are you going to do that on the PC, or in the embedded system?

Comment: A colleague of mine is working within the same kind of specs. His [blog](http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/unit-test-embedded-software-in-3-easy-steps/) contains a lot of valuable information on unit testing and C. He also has some good information on [C, Hudson and code coverage](http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/continuous-code-coverage-with-gcc-googletest-and-hudson/)!

Comment: +1 Ira. Initially, peripherals will be unit tested in s/w. And later integration test with the real board will cover hardrware and software together.